# ubuntu 127.0.0.1 not working, going timeout

Tags: ubuntu, localhost, timeout

Today i've restarted my ubuntu 11.04 server and now the 127.0.0.1 is not working anymore, it still loading for a while and then timeout.

I've tried to make a traceroute and this is the result

```
traceroute 127.0.0.1
traceroute to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

the strange thing is that if I try to connect from php to mysql using 127.0.0.1 it goes on timeout if I try with localhost it works.

I've also tried to telnet to memcached and it goes on timeout both with 127.0.0.1 and localhost

What could it be? I can't find any similar issue anywhere

Comment: Output of `ifconfig`? Did the `lo` adapter vanish somehow?

Comment: Still no update ?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo ifconfig` and see if `lo0` interface is up and running. If not, try `sudo ifconfig lo0 127.0.0.1`.

Have you heavily modified the network settings? If your Ubuntu truly is as ancient as 11.04, then `/etc/network/interfaces` might the file to check out, if my memory serves me right.

Some strange iptables rules might also cause this kind of problems.